# Discord.py buttons

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-buttons

so I want to send an embed with a button that says "I joined" and the user can click it so one invite will go down in the JSON file.

Here is my code:

```py
@client.command()
async def post(ctx, *, content="!"):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    with open("bot-info.json", "r") as f:
        bot_data = json.load(f)


    DISCORD_API_LINK       = "https://discordapp.com/api/invite/"
    DISCORD_GET_IMAGE_LINK = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/"

    channel = client.get_channel(bot_data["nft_projects_channel"])

    if len(content.split(";")) == 3:
        LINK, DESCRIPTION, INVITES = content.split(";")

        invite_code = LINK.split("/")[-1]
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(DISCORD_API_LINK + invite_code) as response:
                data = await response.text()
                json_data = json.loads(data)
                
                try:
                    SERVER_NAME = json_data["guild"]["name"]
                    SERVER_ID   = json_data["guild"]["id"]
                    if json_data["expires_at"] != None:
                        msg = await ctx.send("Warning! invitation has an expiration date, snd an invitation without an expiration date.")
                        await asyncio.sleep(6)
                        await msg.delete()
                        return None
                    try:
                        json_data["inviter"]
                    except:
                        embed = discord.Embed(title="Error", description="Invite Link is not unique", color=0xF54245)
                        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                        await asyncio.sleep(6)
                        await msg.delete()
                        return None
                    SERVER_ICON = str(DISCORD_GET_IMAGE_LINK + SERVER_ID + "/" + json_data["guild"]["icon"] + ".png")
                except:
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="Error", description="Check invite link", color=0xF54245)
                    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                    await asyncio.sleep(6)
                    await msg.delete()
                    return None

        with open("all-servers.json", "r") as read_file:
            data = json.load(read_file)

        if not SERVER_ID in data:
##################################################################################################
            embed = discord.Embed(title = SERVER_NAME, url=LINK, description = DESCRIPTION, color=0xE659ff) #This embed should have the button

            embed.add_field(name="Link:", value=LINK, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Invites Requird:", value=INVITES, inline=False)

            embed.set_thumbnail(url=SERVER_ICON)
            
            await channel.send(embed=embed) #here I am sending it
##################################################################################################

            data[SERVER_ID] = {}
            data[SERVER_ID]["SERVER ID"] = SERVER_ID
            data[SERVER_ID]["INVIRES NEEDED"] = int(INVITES)

            with open("all-servers.json", "w") as write_file:
                json.dump(data, write_file, indent=4)
        else:
            msg = await ctx.send("The server has already been sent.")
            
            await asyncio.sleep(6)
            await msg.delete()
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Error", description=f"Post command requires 3 arguments.\nUseage: `{get_prefix()}post <link>; <description>; <invites required>`\nto post a server on the nft-projects channel", color=0xF54245)
        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await asyncio.sleep(6)
        await msg.delete()
```

After this, the embed should delete itself and delete itself from the JSON File, but I can do this myself, I just need help with the interaction to trigger a function.

thanks, Lior

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How do you try the code? What happens when you do that? How is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: It doesn't have buttons, I need buttons

Comment: Okay. Do you know how to create buttons at all? If not, did you try using a search engine to find out?

Comment: yes, I created with several libraries, but I couldn't find a way to trigger a function and send an embed.
thanks, Lior.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`. It helps to see what can be the problem. And you have to remeber that Disord has own `try/except` which catches all errors so you can't see errors in your code.

Comment: I don't have a problem with my code, I just don't know how to implement the buttons.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to be using discord.py version 2.0.0 for this to work.

To add buttons to a message, you first have to create a view, and then add this view to the message you want to send:

```py
class DeleteEmbedView(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label='I joined', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def delete(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        # This is called once the button is clicked
        await interaction.message.delete() #delete the message with the embed
        # delete it from the JSON file here
```

and then whenever you want to send the button with the message do:

```py
await channel.send(embed=embed, view=DeleteEmbedView())
```

Comment: Do you know how I can do it with reactions? the button isn't very good because a user can press it how much they want to.

Comment: Well a user can press a reaction as much as they want to as well, and you can disable the button or remove the button from the message.

Answer (score 0):

@LoahL code is correct, but I think some time in the past year the argument order has changed for the callback function. I had to swap `interaction` and `button` to get it working.

To clarify, change:

```py
async def delete(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
```

to:

```py
async def delete(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
```

The discord.py Discord server pointed me to the order in the docs:

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.button

> The function being decorated should have three parameters, `self` representing the `discord.ui.View`, the `discord.Interaction` you receive and the `discord.ui.Button` being pressed.