# Discord.py: This interaction failed

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to create a ticket bot using discord buttons. However, whenever I click on the button- which should create a ticket just responds with a prompt saying: "This interaction failed".

[image]

```
    @commands.command(pass_context = True)
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def ticket(self, ctx):
        if self.channelId == 0:
            embed_var = discord.Embed(title="", description="No channel set up [.ticketSet]", color=0xffffff)   
            await ctx.send(embed=embed_var)
        else:
            await self.bot.wait_until_ready() 
            embed_var = discord.Embed(title="Tickets", description=self.ticketDesc, color=0xffffff)   
            channel = self.bot.get_channel(int(self.channelId))
            await channel.send(embed=embed_var,components = [Button(label = " Create Ticket", custom_id = "button1")])

            while True:
                event = await self.bot.wait_for('button_click')
                await self.on_button_click()

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_button_click(self, interaction):
        admin = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, name=self.manageRole)
        category = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.categories, name="INFO / HELP")
        print("Button 'ticket' clicked")
        ...
```

Comment: If you're using the library `discord.py` as stated in the tags of the question, `button_click` is not an event and can't be used in `bot.wait_for`. To add buttons, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70793518/14506951

Comment: What fork of discord.py are you using? discord.py does not have a `Button` (that you imported from where?) so it is unclear how to solve this.